# How do I remove Amazon app but keep google apps?

Tags: webapps

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10. Whenever I go to an amazon webpage it keeps popping up an 'Amazon app' in my Unity taskbar. I find this relatively useless because I'm already on the Amazon website.

I uninstalled it but it ended up uninstalling all my google and other apps as well. When I tried reinstalling the gmail app, it also reinstalled the Amazon app! Is there a way to separate Amazon from the other apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reinstalling [unity-webapps-gmail [image: Install unity-webapps-gmail]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-webapps-gmail)

Comment: Ahh that worked! went through terminal and not firefox and it worked. Solid man, cheers!