# Why removing Amazon also remove other packages?

Tags: unity, uninstall, webapps

If I want to uninstall the Amazon WebApp that comes by default in the newest versions of Ubuntu, it ask me to [remove other software](https://askubuntu.com/q/222342/62483) as well. As you can see in the next picture, it is forcing me to uninstall `unity-webapps-livemail` and `unity-webapps-youtube`.

[image: other_apps]

Is this a bug in Ubuntu or is this intentioned? This behavior will disappear in future releases of Ubuntu?

Comment: I do not know if you would call it a bug or a feature. Part of why Ubuntu is considered easy is that there tend to be longer lists of dependencies compared to othe rdistros. IMO you are best off filing a bug report or feature request.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I'm in that dilemma. Don't know if it's a *bug* or a *feature*..

Comment: I suppose the Ubuntu developers would consider it a feature. I would have to examine the packaging to know why the dependencies are as they have been written.

Comment: This **is** a [bug](http://pad.lv/1079932).

Comment: @Fitoschido Or an *undesirable* feature. Because a bug is not intentioned, and I think that this one is. I hope that in the next release this will be modified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Amazon web app is part of the package `unity-webapps-common` which is needed by all other web apps. So this behaviour is intentioned.

But you can still disable the Amazon integration using dconf-editor or Unsettings as described in  [How do I remove a website from Ubuntu's web applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166655/how-do-i-remove-a-website-from-ubuntus-web-applications)

Comment: Now I understand. I deleted all the entries in the `preauthorized-domains` array with the next command (please, add it to your question) `gsettings set com.canonical.unity.webapps preauthorized-domains []`

Answer (score 5):

The Amazon webapp is—incorrectly, IMHO—baked in `unity-webapps-common`, as Florian correctly says. If you want to remove it without uninstalling the package, do:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/applications/ubuntu-amazon-default.desktop
```

Comment: I'm agree with you. Your command has successfully removed the Amazon icon. Thanks for your support in the *bug*.

Comment: While you're at it, you may want to also do

`sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/ubuntu-amazon-default/`